# Visual studio code uninstall in macbook M1 pro

Tags: installation, homebrew

How can uninstall visual studio code from my MacBook pro M1 laptop completely?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Visual Studio Code from Homebrew, you can just run:

```
brew uninstall visual-studio-code
```